# SQL Server 2008: moving of data between environments

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application which calculates prices for products. There are several tables in database which contain formulas and other logic to calculate prices. These calculation data is different for each product. I have 3 environments: production, release and development. I need a functionality to copy data between them.

For example: admin specifies a date of copying and choose product which should be copied. All pricing data related to this product has to be copied to the required environment at the specific date automatically.

Could you give me an advise what is the best approach to perform this task? Should it be server based logic and scheduler? Or maybe Sql Server job and linked server query? How do I can organize transactions? Etc..

I use SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. An SSIS package - you would make a package that can connect to both servers and check for the run date and then manually move it over.
2. You can create a sql server job, with a linked server query to select from one server and insert into another.
3. You can even create a asp.net service that does this (its the most cumbersome).

In either of these three cases, you can apply transactions across the whole task. IMHO, option #2 is the least painful...

EDIT:

So, if you have never created and SSIS package, this is a good starting point: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CreateFirstSSISPackage.aspx

This is the way to schedule the jobs: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Schedule_Run_SSIS_DTS.aspx

There are plenty of books available on it as well...

Comment: Maybe I will need to copy images between environments during data migration. Images are files in file system. Should I use SSIS packages in that case. Maybe it is more flexible solution?

Comment: yes, then SSIS is the best solution - you can do all of the tasks (file and DB) in one job.

Comment: Thanks. the problem is I don't have any experience in creation of SSIS packages. So, I have additional questions for you: Is it possible to run SSIS packages automatically at the specified time? Is it possible to store settings like connection strings to databases, credentials, file system folders etc. outside of package and pass them to it from an external application before execution, or store them  in a user friendly file from which SSIS package collect these settings? Could you give me some urls where I can read requred information to perform my task?

Comment: yes, you can do all of that. You can encrypt passwords and such. Connections are stored in it as well.... you can then publish the package to be scheduled as a sql server job. Ess my edits to the answer for resources...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SSMS `Import and Export Wizard`.

[How to: Run the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

Comment: As far as I understand, "SSMS Import and Export Wizard" is just one of tools for creation of SSIS packages, isn't it?